# How to extract column names from a list and then use is it in a data frame to select columns based on their name?

Tags: python, list, multiple-columns

I have a dataset of 45 columns and would ONLY like to extract the types numerical ones (int64 and float64)

I tried this

```
mylist = list(df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns)
```

... gave me a list of 28 names

Now, I could do

```
num_df = df[['col1','col13']]
```

but it would be too long ...

Answer (score 0):

something like this :

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['int', 'float'])
```